# How to Add some columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
                                   value
msno              features   days      
B                 num_50     1        0
C                 num_100    3        1
A                 num_100    400      2
```

I used

```
df = df.unstack(level=-1,fill_value = '0')
df = df.unstack(level=-1,fill_value = '0')
df = df.stack()
```

then df looks like :

```
             value
days                         1        3      400
msno              features        
B                 num_50     0        0       0
                  num_100    0        0       0
C                 num_50     0        0       0
                  num_100    0        1       0
A                 num_50     0        0       0
                  num_100    0        0       2
```

Now, I want to fill this df with 0. But still keep original data ,like this:

```
                            value
days                         1     2   3 4 ...    400
msno              features        
B                 num_50     0      0  0 0 ...     0
                  num_100    0      0  0 0 ...     0
C                 num_50     0      0  0 0 ...     0
                  num_100    0      0  1 0 ...     0
A                 num_50     0      0  0 0 ...     0
                  num_100    0      0  0 0 ...     2
```

I want to add columns which are in 1 - 400 and fill the columns by 0.

Could someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `reindex`

```
df.columns=df.columns.droplevel()
df.reindex(columns=list(range(1,20))).fillna(0)

Out[414]: 
days          1    2  3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13  \
msno features                                                                
A    num_100   0  0.0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
     num_50    0  0.0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
B    num_100   0  0.0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
     num_50    0  0.0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
C    num_100   0  0.0  1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
     num_50    0  0.0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
days            14   15   16   17   18   19  
msno features                                
A    num_100   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
     num_50    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
B    num_100   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
     num_50    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
C    num_100   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
     num_50    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: I do not want all value to be 0. I still need to keep the value. You can see that some '1'  and '2' exist in this dataframe

Comment: @AaronWu check column 3 , there is one 1 , I just did not reindex all, You can change list(range(1,20)) to list(range(1,400))

Comment: @AaronWu seems like you do not know how So works , You asked several question , and please accept those answers which help you out.

Comment: an error said.Int64Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'. Should I convert days to str type?

Comment: @AaronWu `droplevel` here  is to drop the 1st level column `value`, if you already do not have it you can ignore that line